# Can anyone tell me in a two column format how can I insert a table?

Tags: tables

[image: It goes beyond the page.][image: This is my requirement]

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\cline{1-10}
          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Settling Time(Ts)} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Overshoot(Osh)}         & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Undershoot(Ush)}      &                             \\ \hline
          & ∆F1         & ∆F2         & ∆Ptie      & ∆F1   (×10-5) & ∆F2 (×10-5) & ∆Ptie (×10-5) & ∆F1 (×10-2) & ∆F2 (×10-2) & ∆Ptie (×10-3) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ITAE}   \\ \hline
CSA Fuzzy & 3.1554      & 6.6794      & 8.5512     & 26.8080       & 9.3532      & 5.4168        & 1.8499      & 0.87764     & 2.3624        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.1253} \\ \hline
CSA 2DOF  & 13.3738     & 14.2868     & 15.8251    & 926.4291      & 1354.1965   & 107.8074      & 2.9397      & 3.6105      & 4.5304        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.6670} \\ \hline
TLBO 2DOF & 10.6906     & 10.9871     & 10.2651    & 121.6417      & 142.3759    & -             & 2.0035      & 1.8185      & 2.5547        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.2325} \\ \hline
DE PID    & 12.3215     & 8.2568      & 14.0917    & 198.5436      & 74.6034     & 19.3058       & 2.6396      & 2.1951      & 4.7337        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.5237} \\ \hline
CSA PID   & 11.7099     & 14.5430     & 22.0996    & 387.3393      & 258.3460    & 44.9078       & 1.9553      & 1.4175      & 3.4565        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.4157} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This is my code and when I try to run it, it obstructs.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which error and/or warning messages you're getting.

Comment: ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ∆ (U+2206)
(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.
See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.

Comment: with this error you have problems with coding, not with tables. please provide compete but small document begining with `documentclass[...]{...}` followed by (relevant part of) preamble, `\begin{document}` some dummy text and examples of your table and ending by `\end{document}`. this will help us and you.

Comment: I agree Sir, i need to turn on mathmode or drop$ to get rid of it. I wanted to know how can i make the table fit into my column. or if not possible is there any command that it will go full without overlapping other text  ?

Comment: Use `\begin{table*} ... \end{table*}`, i.e. add the `*`, then it will span both columns. Which documentclass are you using?

Comment: (i) for inserting tables is intending float `table` (`\begin{table}\caption{...}\label{...} <code of your table>\end{table}` (ii) table width should be les than column width (iii) in case that table need space of two columns, than use `table*`, however table will appear on the top of the next page. for further help, please, consider my previous comment.

Comment: \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(updated the answer to incorporate information from OP about which document class should be used)

Unless you employ a unicode-aware TeX engine (such as XeTeX and LuaTeX) and happen to load the `unicode-math` package, you should start by replacing all instances of `∆` by `\Delta` and all instances of `×` by `\times`. Next, since the table contains 11 columns, you need to find ways to economize on horizontal space. One way to do so is to place the multiplicative scaling factor information in the header cells on separate rows.

Implementing these ideas leads to the upper table in the following screenshot. Note the use of the `table*` environment, which lets the material span both columns, as well as the use of an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment. That way, you'll be typing far fewer `$` symbols to enter and exit math mode.

While the table fits in the available textblock, it's neither particularly attractive nor easy to read. The lower table gives the table a much more open "look", mainly by getting rid of all vertical bars and most horizontal bars. The lower table also aligns the numbers on their decimal markers and applies some rounding: three digits after the decimal markers should be more than enough precision, right? The rounding and aligning is performed by the `S` column type which, in turn, is provided by the `siunitx` package. I hope you will agree with me that the layout of the second table is preferable.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}  % for "\newcolumntype" macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}} % for 1st col.

\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs,siunitx}  % used in second table
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}  % for a marginally more open "look"
\caption{Trying to mimic the OP's screenshot}
\centering
$\begin{array}{|L|*{10}{c|}}
\cline{1-10}
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$Settling Time $ (T_s)} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$Overshoot (Osh)$}
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$Undershoot (Ush)$} \\ 
\hline
& \Delta F_1 & \Delta F_2 & \Delta P_{\mathrm{tie}}   
& \Delta F_1 & \Delta F_2 & \Delta P_{\mathrm{tie}} 
& \Delta F_1 & \Delta F_2 & \Delta P_{\mathrm{tie}}
& $ITAE$ \\
& & & & 
(\times10^{-5}) & (\times10^{-5}) & (\times10^{-5}) & 
(\times10^{-2}) & (\times10^{-2}) & (\times10^{-3}) &  \\ 
\hline
CSA Fuzzy&  3.1554  &  6.6794  &  8.5512 &  26.8080 &    9.3532 &   5.4168 & 1.8499 & 0.87764 & 2.3624 & 0.1253 \\ \hline
CSA 2DOF & 13.3738  & 14.2868  & 15.8251 & 926.4291 & 1354.1965 & 107.8074 & 2.9397 & 3.6105  & 4.5304 & 0.6670 \\ \hline
TLBO 2DOF& 10.6906  & 10.9871  & 10.2651 & 121.6417 &  142.3759 & \textrm{--} & 2.0035 &1.8185& 2.5547 & 0.2325 \\ \hline
DE PID   & 12.3215  &  8.2568  & 14.0917 & 198.5436 &   74.6034 & 19.3058  & 2.6396 & 2.1951  & 4.7337 & 0.5237 \\ \hline
CSA PID  & 11.7099  & 14.5430  & 22.0996 & 387.3393 & 258.3460  & 44.9078  & 1.9553 & 1.4175  & 3.4565 & 0.4157 \\ 
\hline
\end{array}$

\bigskip\bigskip
\setlength\extrarowheight{0pt}  % back to default
\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=3}
\caption{No vertical lines, fewer but well-spaced horizontal lines}
\centering
$\begin{array}{@{} L *{3}{S[table-format=2.3]}
                    *{3}{S[table-format=3.3]}
                    *{4}{S[table-format=1.3]} @{}}
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](lr){2-10}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$Settling Time $ (T_s)} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$Overshoot (Osh)$}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$Undershoot (Ush)$} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-10} 
& {\Delta F_1} & {\Delta F_2} & {\Delta P_{\mathrm{tie}}}    
& {\Delta F_1} & {\Delta F_2} & {\Delta P_{\mathrm{tie}}}  
& {\Delta F_1} & {\Delta F_2} & {\Delta P_{\mathrm{tie}}} 
& {\mathrm{ITAE}}\\
& & & & 
{(\times10^{-5})} & {(\times10^{-5})} & {(\times10^{-5})} & 
{(\times10^{-2})} & {(\times10^{-2})} & {(\times10^{-3})} &  \\ 
\midrule
CSA Fuzzy&  3.1554  &  6.6794  &  8.5512 &  26.8080 &    9.3532 &   5.4168 & 1.8499 & 0.87764 & 2.3624 & 0.1253 \\ 
CSA 2DOF & 13.3738  & 14.2868  & 15.8251 & 926.4291 & 1354.1965 & 107.8074 & 2.9397 & 3.6105  & 4.5304 & 0.6670 \\ 
TLBO 2DOF& 10.6906  & 10.9871  & 10.2651 & 121.6417 &  142.3759 & {\text{--}}& 2.0035& 1.8185 & 2.5547 & 0.2325 \\ 
DE PID   & 12.3215  &  8.2568  & 14.0917 & 198.5436 &   74.6034 & 19.3058  & 2.6396 & 2.1951  & 4.7337 & 0.5237 \\ 
CSA PID  & 11.7099  & 14.5430  & 22.0996 & 387.3393 & 258.3460  & 44.9078  & 1.9553 & 1.4175  & 3.4565 & 0.4157 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: when i negotiated with op for mwe, you made the answer :-). bravo! +1

Comment: @Zarko - Many thanks for the compliment! :-)

Comment: Now it was showing one error with " Illegal pream-token (L): `c' used." when i replaced c with it, all came good but the letters are changed now the CSA PID, TLBO2DOF the entire column font style is changed

Comment: @AdityaNanda - Be sure to load the `array` package. It provides the macro called `\newcolumntype`.